# Синонимизировать метки о разных "data"

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю провести следующие синонимизации:

- [metadata](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metadata) -> [метаданные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5) *(на русском)*
- [data-structures](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structures) -> [структуры-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) *(на русском)*

Comment: Стоит ли две разные синонимизации "упаковывать" в один вопрос?

Comment: @Глеб можно и с другой стороны на ситуацию посмотреть: а стоит ли для каждого синонима плодить отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @Зонтик, ну, может вы и правы...

Comment: @Глеб, просто 1) они все примерно по одной теме 2) сначала их было 3, но потом я решил, что третья не нужна